# How to use Ajax with Django without side modules e.g. endless-pagination

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, pagination

What I need is to make pagination of entries using django Paginator class and load next pages with Ajax. No side-modules like dajax or endless-pagination allowed.

Maybe there is any tutorial about this ?

My problem is that I can not get the whole picture how it should work e.g.
user pushes "next-page" button, then jQuery catch this event and make some magic, then Django make some magic and returns new page to jQuery, then this all loads to page.

It will be great if you can provide such expalantion, even without exact code, just abstract model of how this should be implemented.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much right. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Great, then can you please show how code for each step should look?

Comment: You likely want to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608323