# How to speed up loading lot of images in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I want to speed up the process of loading images in django templates. Now, i'm in a situation that the page will "GET" all the images and then render the page.

part of index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}
{% for new in news_list %}
    <div class="card">
    {% thumbnail new.image "250x250"  as im %}
       <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
    {% endthumbnail %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

part of view.py

```
from .models import News

def home(request):
   news_list = News.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'index.html', news_list)
```

i used chrome "F12" to see what is happened. It takes so long for 'GET' all images. I think it's not the issue of getting a large models. Is there another way to display some images in templates instead of get all the images? Thankyou so much.

Comment: A possible solution is to add pagination to your News module and call the first 10 or 20 news articles on load and use Ajax for Next Page calls.

Comment: could you explain more how to use ajax? get model data using ajax instead of render in view.py? @Sam

Comment: These are two articles that might help you to get started and understand :

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Also this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608323/django-core-paginator-ajax-pagination-with-jquery

Comment: thanks @Sam for saving my time. It's helpful

Answer (score 2):

When you have really **a lot** of images, solution here is to load images on demand. Like user scrolls down and get new images downloaded.

Like [jquery-loadscroll](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/jQuery-Plugin-To-Smartly-Load-Images-While-Scrolling-loadScroll.html) plugin could be used

**UPD** As @Kurohige mentioned below, you have to optimize images for web as well. By optimizing he means looseless image size compression

Comment: Also I would suggest an image optimizer for web

Comment: @Kurohige makes sense